# Css h2 possition with background center

Tags: html, css

Hi i have this css code for my H2

```
rightBox h2 {

background: url(images/lineh2.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
margin-bottom: 15px;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 100;
font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
color: #00b4f0;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
```

This add above title line 40x5px, and poistion is 0px left, I want to move title on center with `text-align: center;` but i want the line show on center also but in left corner with text like this:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a span element inside where you apply your background that you can simplify with a gradient:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  color: #00b4f0;
  text-align:center;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
h2 span {
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(currentColor,currentColor) top left/40px 5px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Some text</span></h2>
```

In case you cannot change the HTML here is another way but without transparency:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", Tahoma, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  color: #00b4f0;
  display:flex;
  line-height:45px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  background:
    linear-gradient(currentColor,currentColor) top left/50% 5px no-repeat;
}
h2::before,
h2::after{
  content:"";
  flex-grow:1;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some text</h2>
```